# Can an (extended) regular grammar have multiple nonterminals in its RHS?

Tags: regex, regular-language

Standard (right) regular grammars have three kinds of rules:

```
A <- ""
A <- "a"
A <- "a" B
```

This is OK for a theoretical point of view, but a big inconvenience to usable in practice. A practical regular grammar should allow us to use commodity operators (`|`,`*`,`+`,`?`,`.`,`(`,`)`), character sets and group multiple rules in a single one. For example, the following regular grammar describes fractional numbers:

```
start <- digit+ dot digit* | digit* dot digit+
digit <- [0-9]
dot   <- '.'
```

The question is, what restrictions must be applied to RHS non-terminals to keep this grammars regular (if it is possible at all)?

**NOTE**

Q - *Why regular grammars instead of regular expressions?*

A - Regular expressions are OK for simple languages, but they are write-only for more complex ones. On the other hand, well written extended regular grammars are allot more readable and maintainable and allows us to extend them with captures and rule actions easily.

Comment: This isn't actually about programming. You will get better luck asking on CS.SE

Answer (score 0):

> what restrictions must be applied to RHS non-terminals to keep this grammars regular

Basically you don't want to invent new grammar rules, you just want a notational (syntactic) abbreviation for multiple grammar rules into a single one. And that's the restriction: you must have some definitions for the new syntax about how to translate it "back" into a finite number of strictly (right) regular grammar rules.

For the examples you've given, that's

- `A <- α | β` ⇒ `A <- α; A <- β`
- `A <- [αβ…]` ⇒ `A <- α; A <- β; …`
- `A <- .` ⇒ `A <- [Σ]`
- `A <- B ?` ⇒ `A <- ε; A <- B`
- `A <- B *` ⇒ `A <- X; X <- ε; X <- BX`
- `A <- B +` ⇒ `A <- X; X <- B; X <- BX`

Here we've got a problem, as `X <- BX` is not a regular grammar rule. We can however make copies of `B` and all its subterms that allow this:

- `B <- ε` ⇒ `BX <- X`
- `B <- α` ⇒ `BX <- α X`
- `B <- α C` ⇒ `BX <- α CX` (then do the same for `CX`)

In general, you can use a whole regular expression for the terminal parts of your grammar rules. Just convert it to a regular grammar and append the respective non-terminal to all final rules.